# How could I edit html tables in PhpStorm?

Tags: html, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm to edit html and php. Great editor but I can't find useful features:

1. How could I insert row and column in html table (in html file).
2. How could I delete row or column in html table (in html file)

Or there is no ways to do that?

Answer (score 3):

To insert new row to HTML table write

```
<tr><td></td>...<td></td></tr>
```

To delete row, select all code between matching `<tr>` and `</tr>` (including these tags), find <kbd>delete</kbd> button and press to delete selected text.

---

You can <kbd>ALT</kbd> + CLICK to place multiple markers.
<kbd>CTRL + D</kbd> will copy same line to below.
You can use <kbd>CTRL + F</kbd> to replace text using RegExp.

Other than that, use PHP to generate table in loop instead of manual writing.

---

**You Will ALWAYS have to deal with code manipulation by hand**

Comment: suppose I have table with 20 rows and 20 columns with content in they.
I need to delete 13 th column.
what should I do? find every 13th td , select it and press delete. And so do 20 times? Very helpfull answer...